# What is a performance impact of "ovm is match" function?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I would like to understand "ovm_is_match" function performance impact. 
Where can i see the internal function implementation?

Thanks

Comment: ovm is a separate package, so find where it is installed. It has all the verilog sources in it.

Answer (score 0):

All of the source code for the OVM is available under the Apache license. You can usually find it in the source tree of your simulator, or you can look [here](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/ovmworld/docs_2.1.2/html/files/base/ovm_globals-svh.html#ovm_is_match). Since the OVM was written, most simulators have extended SystemVerilog to support built-in string match functions. Check your user manual.